# How to store data in a database in Windows Phone Runtime?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I give up now after 3 days of searching!

I want to store data in a database in my Windows Phone Runtime app, but couldn't find a proper database solution.

I checked [`SQLite-net`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/) but it doesn't support a simple relationship between classes. So I couldn't define a list of items in my classes.

Then I installed [`SQLite-net Extensions`](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) as a solution to that problem. but it doesn't have a proper package for `Windows Phone Runtime`. It needs a `ISQLitePlatform` implementation as a parameter in `SQLiteConnection()` which only god knows where to find the right dll.

So my question is, all these apps available, what database they use? how can I store my data in a DataBase?

Comment: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/nicholas-cipollina/cross-platform-sqlite-support-%E2%80%93-part-1

Comment: I tried to use SQLite-net for over a week and ran through a lot of issues until I was finally able to get it up and running. I also played with SQLite-net Extensions for the same reasons as you do. Finally, today I switched over to iBoxDB [link](http://www.iboxdb.com/). To model my relationship there I created another property that actually serialized my child objects into a Json string (you could do the same in SQLite of course). Btw. it took me just 3 hours to set up iBoxDB although they don't have that much documentation apart from a very complex sample file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

It seems they fixed the issue a couple of hours ago. See: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issue/27/error-while-adding-sqlite-net-extension-to

**Old Post**

Yes. You're right. This is not included by default and you will have to do many things on your own. But implementing relationships is not that hard:

```
// Query entity A
var AList = App.DB.Table<EntityA>().ToList();
if (AList == null || AList.Count == 0)
    return;
// Get entity B for each item
foreach (EntityA ea in AList)
{
    // I'm retreiving just a single element here.. of course you can easily pull a list here for one to many relationships..
    var eb = App.DB.Table<EntityB>().Where(b => b.EntityAIndex == ea.DBId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (eb == null)
        continue;
    ea.EntityB = eb;
}
```

But SQLite is the way to go here and unless you're not working with millions of records pulling a simple relationship from your DB won't take too much time (I have 3rd degree relationships and they are retrieved instantly). All you have to do is setting the foreign key manually when you add objects to your DB. But that's a single line of code.

```
entityA.entityBId = entityB.DBId;
```

Also writing the code to read entities with relationships is not that much of a hassle. Sure, that's nothing you would want to write manually but it's just a few extra lines.

Btw: I am using sqlite-net.

Comment: Thanks, that is great! Now it supports Windows Phone Runtime.

Comment: Yes. But as you can see from my code - It's not that big of a deal. And as soon as these extensions are stable you can just replace your code.